# Book about a Magic School set in a castle

Tags: story-identification, magic

Looking for a book that takes place at some kind of magic castle in England. I remember there being something about a magic rock inside of a mirror.

I read this sometime in the early nineties, which is how I know **it's not a Harry Potter novel.**  There was also something about brothers and I remember something at the end of the novel about a magic painting.

The book's cover was green or blue. This was originally read in Russian.

Comment: i feel like were being trolled.

Comment: Can you provide more details? When and where you read this, other details about the plot? Characters? Vague memories of a book cover?

Comment: Guys, it CAN'T be Harry Potter, I mean, obviously. The two description are NOTHING alike. Hogwarts is in Scotland ;)

Comment: I read it sometime in the early nineties, which is how I know it's not harry potter. There was something about these brothers. Cover was green or blue, I don't remember much more than that.

Comment: I agree. In the absence of any additional info, this reads like trolling. Can you remember anything about the characters (male/female/ages)? The events of the novel (quest/villains/items)? What made the castle magical? Was the novel in English?

Comment: Not English, Russian.

Comment: @HarrisonHolmes - Any answer to the other questions? How **certain** are you about the dates you read it?

Comment: I am pretty sure I read this before any of the books mentioned was published.  
I remember something at the end of the novel about a magic painting, but I'm not sure what it was regarding.

Comment: There is a list of books at http://librarybooklists.org/mybooklists/potterlike.htm that are "Potter like", several of which are set at schools of magic. You might take a gander and see if any titles spark a memory.

Comment: Also, http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WizardingSchool, the Literature section.

Comment: I looked at those lists and it almost seems like the book I remember was an very badly translated bootleg rip off of Wheel of Time and The Book of Three.

Comment: @HarrisonHolmes: Honestly, due to differences of copyright, those are not uncommon in Russia as I understand it. There's a rewritten Lord of the Rings that's actually more popular than the original.

Comment: theres also a russian bootleg of the harry potter series the first book is very close to philosopher stone, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanya_Grotter

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/a-young-adult-novel-that-has-a-boy-who-goes-to-a-school-for-wizards-and-is-no

Answer (score 6):

Could it be [Wizard's Hall](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/271060.Wizard_s_Hall) by Jane Yolen?  It came out in 1991 and has been frequently compared to the Harry Potter series.

An 11 year old boy goes to a school for wizards with magic moving pictures on the walls and stars on the ceiling, where he makes friends with a red haired boy and a brainy girl. He saves the school from an evil wizard.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're possibly thinking of the third book of the [Septimus Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septimus_Heap) series, *[Physik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septimus_Heap#The_novels)*. The great alchemist, Marcellus Pye, pulls Septimus through a mirror and back in time to help create the elixir of eternal youth, which is tied to the Philosopher's Stone, much like in Harry Potter. It is indeed set in a castle, albeit not in England as we know it.

Septimus comes from a family with seven boys (he is a Seventh Son of a Seventh Son), but is separated from them at the beginning of the first book and instead Jenna, the lost Princess, is raised by the Heaps.

I've found two different sets of covers:

[image: Covers of the Septimus Heap series with differently colored backgrounds and minimal illustration]

[image: Alternate covers for the Septimus Heap series with dramatic images of characters in the book, with differently colored backgrounds]

The only major catch is that they were released between 2005 and 2013, so the time frame you mention above does not match.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that it's *[Groosham Grange](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/378356.Groosham_Grange)* by Anthony Horowitz? It came out in 1988, so the timeframe might fit, and several of the covers are blue. I haven't found a Russian cover, but it has been translated into multiple languages. It follows a boy named David Elliot who is sent to the eponymous school of magic. A magic mirror is a major part of the plot, although I haven't found any reference to magic stones yet.