# Book (maybe series) about someone going to a magic academy, who has no magic of his own, but can act as a conduit/amplifier for the magic of others

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

The main character is seemingly a magical dude. He, I think the character was a he, and has no magic of his own at an academy of magic. Turns out he's a conduit. If he touches another magic user he can use and amplify their power and even combine multiple people's magic into one if they are all touching. I'm pretty sure this was a series.

I read this somewhere between 2000 and 2010, but probably closer to 2000, I believe. It is a kids book. For some reason I want to say the kid was albino and/or had glasses... but there's no real remembrance. I don't remember if they used witch, wizard, sorcerer, or some other word for a magic user.

Answer (score 3):

### Wizard's Hall, by Jane Yolen

[Wizard's Hall](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard%27s_Hall) is about Henry (aka Thornmallow), a young boy who goes to the Wizarding school to become a wizard.  He turns out to be unable to do magic on his own, but his ability to enhance the magic of others and his willingness to really try ends up saving the day when the dark wizard Nettle attacks the school.

Thornmallow is depicted with white hair on the cover, probably why you remember him as albino.

> “Thornpower asks if he has a talent for magic.” She smiled slowly and shook her head. “He does not. At least, he does not have a talent for enchantment. His talent is far greater. He has a talent for enhancement. He can make any spell someone else works even greater simply by trying.”

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/a-young-adult-novel-that-has-a-boy-who-goes-to-a-school-for-wizards-and-is-no/4542#4542